# reactive approach while using useReducer hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have starting to play around with react hooks. I was looking into various examples of `useReducer`. I see that in order to access `redux store` and `dispatch` event in your component, we use `[state, dispatch] = useReducer(initState)`. I was wondering, how is the reactive approach of `React` could be implemented in which we use to do `mapStateToProps` and then on selective properties of state only our components use to react. I would appreciate it if this is answered with an example.
According to my understanding all the components in which we write `[state, dispatch] = useReducer(initState)`, all those components will re-render, even if we don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

First, `useReducer` is not related to Redux. It's just [an alternative](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to `useState` and will be helpful in case where your state has complex transformation flow.

React-Redux [provides](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) `useSelector`, `useStore` and `useDispatch`. Once you use `useSelector` it already [does optimization](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) under the hood:

> However, when an action is dispatched to the Redux store, useSelector() only forces a re-render if the selector result appears to be different than the last result. As of v7.1.0-alpha.5, the default comparison is a strict === reference comparison. This is different than connect(), which uses shallow equality checks on the results of mapState calls to determine if re-rendering is needed. This has several implications on how you should use useSelector().

This is main reason why we should avoid `useStore` at any cost(any dispatch will trigger re-render for it).

Comment: An example for all the concept of `react-redux` hooks along with `typescript` implemented in git repo: https://github.com/shahkartik03/React-Redux_typescript.